# composer PSR-4 autoloader Fatal error: Class not found

Tags: php, composer-php

I have created an app directory and autoloaded it using PSR-4 like this:

```
"psr-4": {
    "App\\": "app/"
}
```

And I also did composer dumpautoload. I have the following directory structure:

```
/var/www/html/project
                    composer,json
                    composer.lock
                    app/models/Product.php
                    api/v1/index.php
                    ....
```

my Product.php is this:

```
?php
namespace App\Models;
....
```

Finally my index.php is this:

```
use App\Models\Product;
```

But I always get fatal error fatal error: Class 'App\Models\Product' not found not found in [/var/www/html/ ...]

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you've added the model without using PHP Artisan command `php artisan make:model Product`. Anyway, try the following two:

1. Do a `composer update`
2. If (1) doesn't solve the problem, you'd probably have to
   modify your `autoload-dev` key in your composer.json and then do
   `composer dump-autoload`:

   ```
   "autoload-dev": {
   "classmap": [  
       "app/models/Product.php"
       ]
   }, /** ... */
   ```